# Invalid default value for timestamp type column in Toad

Tags: mysql, toad

I am working in ToadForMySQL and I have a table that I created where there are 2 timestamp type columns:

MatchStartDate
MatchEndDate

I had set the default for the MatchStartDate to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and MatchEndDate was set as 0000-00-00 00:00:00.  However, now I want to set each column with a default value of:  1970-01-01 00:00:00

However, when I try to do that for the MatchStartDate column I get the following error:

Invalid default value for 'MatchStartDate'

Here is the SQL Script:

```
ALTER TABLE Think.DirectMailList
 CHANGE MatchStartDate MatchStartDate TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:00';
```

Any suggestions/direction would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not a valid TIMESTAMP; you need to add 1 second.

[The DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html)

> The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. 
>   TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE DirectMailList (MatchStartDate TIMESTAMP);

ALTER TABLE DirectMailList
 CHANGE MatchStartDate MatchStartDate TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01';
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28a9c)

Comment: I appreciate the response. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Hey Karl, I tried adding 1 second as you indicated above but still getting the same error.  Any other suggestions would be appreciated.  Here is what I added in the default value field:  1970-01-01 00:00:01 Thanks.

Comment: interesting. I've updated with a working example and a fiddle. Seems like that is working. Are you getting exactly the same error now?

Comment: Yes. I just decided to enter 0000-00-00 00:00:00 and it took it just fine.  Thanks.

Comment: Okay.for what it worth, when I run my example with '1970-01-01 00:00:00' i get the error and when I use '1970-01-01 00:00:01' instead there is no error. What version are you using?

Comment: I am using Toad For MySQL 7.0.0.2038

Comment: Sorry. What version of MySQL rather than Toad? I would hope Toad is just passing through the DML to apply to the DB.